# How to get MacBook's "(1P) Part ID" programatically in swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, hardware-id

I was required to get the part number and the serial number. I have searched various pods and GitHub code snippets but I could not not get any lead on how to the `(1P) Part No.`.

I have used **SystemKit** and **GBDeviceinfo** get informations like model, RAM space, CPU core. But I could not get the part number with any of them.

So can anyone help me to get some lead on how I can get the `(1P) Part ID No` programatically for a MacBook or any Mac device that one.

[image]

Comment: IDK how sensitive these details are, but just in case, I'd suggest you obfuscate your mac addresses and serial number.

Comment: @Alexander noted and done

Comment: That's a stocking number for the store. I doubt it's embedded anywhere on the system. You can verify by doing "system_profiler | grep THATNUMBER". If it doesn't show, it's not available from a running system.